# Converting 12 bit color values to 8 bit color values C++

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, colors

I'm attempting to convert 12-bit RGGB color values into 8-bit RGGB color values, but with my current method it gives strange results.

Logically, I thought that simply dividing the 12-bit RGGB into 8-bit RGGB would work and be pretty simple:

```
// raw_color_array contains R,G1,G2,B in a bayer pattern with each element
// ranging from 0 to 4096
for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
    raw_color_array[i] /= 16; // 4096 becomes 256 and so on
}
```

However, in practice this actually does not work. Given, for example, a small image with water and a piece of ice in it you can see what actually happens in the conversion (right most image).

[image][image]

Why does this happen? and how can I get the same (or close to) image on the left, but as 8-bit values instead? Thanks!

**EDIT**: going off of @MSalters answer, I get a better quality image but the colors are still drasticaly skewed. What resources can I look into for converting 12-bit data to 8-bit data without a steep loss in quality?

Comment: Have you tried taking a histogram on the channels to see if you should perhaps be favoring certain ranges, instead of the wide-open divide-by-16 approach?

Comment: Have you debugged and observed the values of `raw_color_array`? Are they what you expect?  What is the data type of `raw_color_array`?  Have you got a rounding error?

Comment: @ChrisO Indeed, the first iteration of my attempt was eyeing a histogram and guessing a normalizing scheme. It generated near identical results, but it's not a scalable solution (e.g. I would need to re-do this process for 14-bit color images and so on). Was wondering if this is possible without kind of eyeing it.

Comment: Since you want to convert the data to different sizes. You have to accept that when the target data size is smaller (from 12bits to 8bits) then its going to loose some of its data. Now, to get the closest match of the color intensity after conversion, you need to compute the ratio between 12bits and your target conversion. I already presented the formula in my answer.

Comment: You say "RGB" but the code says "RGGB".  That's probably intentional (makes sense in combination with "bayer pattern")  but it might very well explain why your result seems greenish.

Comment: @MSalters is right. If you reduce the bits of the raw bayer pattern the look will change more than reducing the bits of the debayered color image. You could lookup some quantization algorithms that offer better results than simple division.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your raw 12 bits data isn't on a linear scale. That is quite common for images. For a non-linear scale, you can't use a linear transformation like dividing by 16.

A non-linear transform like `sqrt(x*16)` would also give you an 8 bits value. So would `std::pow(x, 12.0/8.0)`

A known problem with low-gradient images is that you get banding. If your images has an area where the original value varies from say 100 to 200, the 12-to-8 bit reduction will shrink that to less than 100 different values. You get rounding , and with naive (local) rounding you get bands. Linear or non-linear, there will then be some inputs x that all map to y, and some that map to y+1. This can be mitigated by doing the transformation in floating point, and then adding a random value between -1.0 and +1.0 before rounding. This effectively breaks up the band structure.

Comment: Thanks! Both the `sqrt(x*16)` and `std::pow(x, 12/8)` work sooo much better than a linear transformation.

My image seems to have become greyish greener however, is there a way to combat it? The blue ocean water has become much more faint and green as a result.

Answer (score 1):

After you clarified that this 12bit data is only for one color, here is my simple answer:

Since you want to convert its value to its 8 bit equivalent, it obviously means you lost some of the data (4bits). This is the reason why you are not getting the same output.

Comment: the 12 bits in question actually represent a 12 bit color value of **one** color. In my case there are 2^12 possible red values, and I want to convert it to 2^8 possible red values. Each specific element only represents one color, and the colors are arranged in a bayer pattern of Red Green Red the first row, and Green Blue Green the second row

Comment: Regardless of how much number of bits you intend to use. The point of my answer is if your going to have a different range or conversion, you need to compute for the ratio of that target range. The formula is already presented in my answer. If you want to convert 2^12 bit to 2^8 bit which as you said represents one color only. Then get the highest possible red values and divide.

24(2X12)   /    16(2^8)   =   1.5
Actual value /1.5 is the actual conversion to 2^8
ex.  24     /     1.5     =     16 which gives you the highest number in 2^8 as well

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote  24(2 * 12) / 16(2^8) = 1.5. If I wanted to compute highest max value of 12 bits divided by highest max value of 8 bits, would it not be `4096 (2^12) / 256 (2^8) = 16`. And 16 is what I'm using in the code sample I wrote in the OP

Comment: Sorry i was confused. You are correct its suppose to be 2 to the 12th  and 2 to the 16th. And you are correct of using 16 as the ratio. We can conclude that the reason why you are getting a different output is because some of the values was lost in the conversion as i have mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

After clarification: 
If you want to retain the actual colour values! 
Apply de-mosaicking in the 12 Bit image and then scale the resultant data to 8 - Bit. So that the colour loss due to de-mosaicking will be less compared to the previous approach.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your 12-bits represent 2^12 bits of one colour. That is incorrect. There are reds, greens and blues in your image. Look at the histogram. I made this with ImageMagick at the command line:

```
convert cells.jpg histogram:png:h.png
```

[image]

If you want 8-bits per pixel, rather than trying to blindly/statically apportion 3 bits to Green, 2 bits to Red and 3 bits to Blue, you would probably be better off going with an 8-bit palette so you can have 250+ colours of all variations rather than restricting yourself to just 8 blue shades, 4 reds an 8 green. So, like this:

```
convert cells.jpg -colors 254 PNG8:result.png
```

Here is the result of that beside the original:

[image][image]

The process above is called *"quantisation"* and if you want to implement it in C/C++, there is a writeup [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/quantize.php).

Comment: If the RGB bit pattern would be RGB 444, dividing by 16 and reinterpreting the result as RGB323 would discard all 4 blue bits and reinterpret the 3 lowest bits of the original green channel as blue. No, that is definitely not happening.

Comment: I only used a JPG so I could actually display the image, in reality the image is a 0,1,1,2 pattern on a `.NEF` file. That would mean I still have `2^12` bits per color yes?